# probably stupid bug in code

Tags: javascript, jquery

What reason this code works perfectly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#login_form").submit(function() {
                $.post("ajax_login.php", {
                    nam: $('#nam').val(),
                    mPassword: $('#mPassword').val()
                }, function(data) {
                    if (data == 'yes') {
                        $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200, 0.1, function() {
                            $(this).html('Log').addClass('messageboxok').fadeTo(900, 1, function() {
                                document.location = 'secure.php';
                            });
                        });
                    } else {
                        $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200, 0.1, function() {
                            $(this).html('Login inválido').addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900, 1);
                        });
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

and this code doesn't work? (none message is showed) it have any bug?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#login_form").submit(function() {
            $.post("ajax_login.php", {
                nam: $('#nam').val(),
                mPassword: $('#mPassword').val()
            }, function(data) {
                if (data == 'yes') {
                    $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200, 0.1, function() {
                        $(this).html('Log').addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900, 1);
                    });
                } else {
                    $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200, 0.1, function() {
                        $(this).html('Logging in.....').addClass('messageboxok').fadeTo(900, 1, function() {
                            document.location = 'secure.php';
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
            return false;
        });

    });
</script>
```

edit: two scripts works

the question is related to the second example. What is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks to me that you prematurely closed the `if` statement in your second code sample.  It now looks like the `else` applies to the `function` and not the `if`.

Edit:  There seems to still be a problem with some placement in your code (namely the `return false` statement in the second code).  Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#login_form").submit(function() {
            $.post("ajax_login.php", {
                nam: $('#nam').val(),
                mPassword: $('#mPassword').val()
            }, function(data) {
                if (data == 'yes') {
                    $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200, 0.1, function() {
                        $(this).html('Log').addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900, 1);
                    });
                } else {
                    $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200, 0.1, function() {
                        $(this).html('Logging in.....').addClass('messageboxok').fadeTo(900, 1, function() {
                            document.location = 'secure.php';
                        }); 
                    });
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: in you code is missing in the last line one more  });. now works- thanks

Answer (score 3):

In the second function you have:

```
function(data) {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

You can't have an `else` clause on a function. It seems that you have some ending brackets in the wrong place.